# How can I loosely couple database columns in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, unity-container, loose-coupling

I have two versions of an almost identical database.  Below I have created an Example table to demonstrate the basic differences, namely the ID column has changed from an Integer Identity to a GUID and various properties have been updated, in the Example archived has been replaced with readOnly and hidden:

Legacy version:

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
    --Data Identity (maps to DbId in the example code)
    Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,

    --Example columns
    SomeValue varchar(50),
    AnotherValue int,

    --Data Properties
    Archived bit
)
```

New version:

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
    --Data Identity (maps to DbId in the example code)
    Id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY,

    --Example columns
    SomeValue varchar(50),
    AnotherValue int,

    --Data Properties
    ReadOnly bit,
    Hidden bit
)
```

I need to be able to use an O/R mapper such as NHibernate to connect to one or other of these database versions.  I would like to be able to tell the application which version to use through settings in a configuration file.

My initial plan was to create a common interface for the business logic and use an IoC container such as Unity to swap between the relevant concrete classes in the configuration file.

Below is an example of the code I created to test this theory:

```
public interface IDataIdentity
{
    object Id { get; }
}

public class LegacyDataIdentity : IDataIdentity
{
    public virtual long DbId { get; set; }

    public object Id
    {
        get { return DbId; }
    }
}

public class NewDataIdentity : IDataIdentity
{
    public virtual Guid DbId { get; set; }

    public object Id
    {
        get { return DbId; }
    }
}


public interface IDataProperties
{
    bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    bool Hidden { get; set; }
}

public class LegacyDataProperties : IDataProperties
{
    public virtual bool Archived { get; set; }

    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get { return Archived; }
        set { Archived = value; }
    }

    public bool Hidden
    {
        get { return Archived; }
        set { Archived = value; }
    }
}

public class NewDataProperties : IDataProperties
{
    public virtual bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Hidden { get; set; }
}


public class DataItem
{
    public DataItem(IDataIdentity dataIdentity, IDataProperties dataProperties)
    {
        DataIdentity = dataIdentity;
        DataProperties = dataProperties;
    }

    public IDataIdentity DataIdentity { get; set; }
    public IDataProperties DataProperties { get; set; }
}

public class Example : DataItem
{
    public Example(IDataIdentity dataIdentity, IDataProperties dataProperties)
        : base(dataIdentity, dataProperties)
    {
    }

    public virtual string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public virtual int AnotherValue { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone advise if this is possible (specifically with Unity and NHibernate) and if so how to create the relevant NHibernate mapping files?

Alternatively, can anyone suggest any solution to the problem using any other methods or other IoC and O/R mapping tools (commercial or open source)?

Many thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 2):

Why not abstract your data provider, implementing 2 versions (one with nhibernate mappings for the legacy data item, and one for the new data item).

To paraphrase your code slightly (simplified for clarity):

```
public abstract class AbstractData
{
    public abstract string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public abstract bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    //etc.
}

public interface IDataProvider
{
    AbstractData Get(object id);
}

public class LegacyData : AbstractData
{
     // Implement AbstractData, and
     public virtual long Id { get { return m_Id; } set { m_Id = value; };
     private long m_Id;
}

public class LegacyDataNHibernateProvider : IDataProvider
{
     public LegacyDataProvider()
     {
         // Set up fluent nhibernate mapping 
     }

     public AbstractData Get(object id)
     {
           // Interpret id as legacy identifier, retrieve LegacyData item, and return
     }
};

// Same again for new data provider
```

This way, you aren't tied to nhibernate (or a database, for that matter), and you can specify concrete classes with correctly typed identifiers (which nhibernate can handle). This is the approach I'm taking, where I currently have to map against an existing database's SPs, but will later migrate to a new ORM-based system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly, but it sounds to me like you need to implement something like the "Factory Pattern".

I recently used the factory pattern to code (c#) to two data layers when the company I work for was switching from JDE to SAP. I was able to flip a config switch to switch between the two data layers, and the GUI wouldn't know any different.

Here's a couple links I found:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954600.aspx
http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/factory_pattern.htm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

As far as NHibernate goes, I'm not familiar with it... sorry.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to recommend without knowing the full picture, but.... You can create an abstruction in the SPs by having SP return identical dataset for both table structures.

Another abstruction I am thinking of, is you can actually specify different hybernate mapping files, and initialize Hibernate with a different file depending on what database you connect to.